# OpenLayers 6 many layers on the map performance

Tags: openlayers, wms, performance

I have around 50 layers which I need to add to the map though wms, however the performance is really bad. Including that for each layer is triggered the wms layer events.

```
const source = new TileWMS({
   url: `${baseWmsUrl}${url.pathname}`,
   tileLoadFunction: (imageTile, src) => loadTileImage(imageTile, src),
   params,
});

new TileLayer({
  source,
  zIndex: 0,
})
```

I have read that it can combine multiple LAYERS in single wms request, however that seems not working for me as I have control which sets the opacity of each individual layer, including the click event which is looking for each layer at a pixel and also specific style per layer. I tried layer group but it doesn`t help to improve the speed.

Are there any options I can improve the OpenLayers performance with that much layers on the map?